# Pentaho - Reuse field Multiple Times in a query

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a field, item_id, being passed from one transform step to another. I want to use that field multiple times in the next transform step for use in a UNION.

select x, y from table1 where item_id = ?
UNION
select w, z from table2 where item_id = ?

Since transforms do placeholder replacement in order by field, how do I make the item_id available to be used multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make the two queries in a separate `Input tables` and direct the flow on the same step (next step can be any step):

[image]

An other way is to use parameters instead of variable:

```
select x, y from table1 where item_id = "${myParam}" UNION select w, z from table2 where item_id = "${myParam}".
```

An third way is the rewrite the query as

```
select * from (select x, y from table1 UNION select w, z from table2) where item_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Select task to duplicate the values.  Keeps it simple.